# joomla 2.5.6: how to remove date from url

Tags: joomla2.5

I created articles with alias **overview-of-trips** but when I try to view the article url become **index.php/destinations/2012-08-08-05-05-05/thailand/overview-of-trips** it should be 
 some thing like **index.php/destinations/thailand/overview-of-trips**

I queried in **xma7k_content** db table to find this date/time, but I don't know from where it attaches this date/time.

```
Menu Item Type is : Single Article
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your category (destinations) **alias** it must be date so it is appearing like this.